# Default unix time value in flask SQLAlchemy object

Tags: python, mysql, time, sqlalchemy

I am trying to store the unix timestamp of the moment an object is created by default. However, I always get the same wrong value when the object is stored in the database. Here is my class:

```py
from time import time

class Notification(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128), index=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.Float, index=True, default=time)
    payload_json = db.Column(db.Text)

    def get_data(self):
        return json.loads(str(self.payload_json))
```

If I start a flask shell:

```
>>>from time import time
>>>time()
1571733064.7366862
>>>n=Notification(name='dummy')
db.session.add(n)
>>> db.session.commit()
>>> n.timestamp
1571730000.0
```

Any insights on what is going on here??!!! I checked in a Mysql shell and SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() gives the right value.

thanks in advance

Comment: If SQLAlchemy's generic type `Float` ends up as single precision `FLOAT` in MySQL, then it cannot store such a large value with such precision.

Comment: What's the reason for using float instead of the MySQL datetime type?

Comment: thanks. I periodically check for new notifications since the last one froma function in javscript. At a point it seemed simpler to work with floats than with datetime objects because of using both  programming languages. I guess I could also do it with a datetime object. It was something that in principle seemed striaght forward and it turned out a complicated issue. After Ilja's comment I changed the data type to BigInteger and convert the time() to an integer number of milliseconds (int(time()*1000). It works. I will wait to see if there is a better solution and if not I will publish it.